# Cancelling specific task in a dataflow ActionBlock

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

After spending all day searching I came across a comment that TPL Dataflow cancellation comes out of the box as a way to cancel an entire block, and not an individual task/item.    My main stumbling block is how do I go about cancelling Task #5 if my Action block is concurrently running 10 tasks in parallel?   There are quite a few cancellation examples out there, but they all use just one cancellation token, and end up cancelling Task #5 and all the tasks after it.

Here is some very stripped down code.  I am guessing I have to pass something along with "i", but unclear how to programatically create unique cancellation tokens, coupled with the fact I may need anywhere from 1 to 10 of them in this particular example.  Even if I create a cancellation token in the mouse-click method, do I then have to check it against existing tokens to make sure it is unique? So confused.

```
            // Define the action block
        ActionBlock<int> throttle = new ActionBlock<int>(
            action: i=>DoStuff(i),
            dataflowBlockOptions: new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
            {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10,
                CancellationToken = cts.Token
            });

        // Create the work set (pretend it is a mouse-click method... it will not be a for loop)
        for (int i = 0; i < work.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{i:D3} : Posting Work Item {i}.");
            throttle.Post(i);
        }
```

Comment: The `DoStuff` method doesn't seem to be cancelable, since it's not accepting a `CancellationToken` parameter. Could you include the code of this method in your question?

Comment: As I said, the code shown is very stripped down, and my main question was HOW to replace (or modify) "i" in DoStuff(i) with code that would make each work element individually cancel-able. Sorry if it was unclear.  Kinda like "I have these words, but how do I string a sentence".

Comment: So would you like to know how to make a cancelable method? The official tutorial is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads), and it is quite good.

Comment: I looked at it but doesn't seem to have any examples for the TPL-Dataflow approach which I am using (and starting to regret).

Comment: What about the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59186898/11178549) proposed by John Wu? Isn't it sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to stop them, you need a list of cancellation token sources so that you can signal them individually. If you want one per element in `work` you could just select over it:

```
var sources = work.Select( w => new CancellationTokenSource()).ToList();
```

Then, you have to modify `DoStuff` to check the token:

```
void DoStuff(int i, CancellationToken token)
{
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        //Do the rest of the stuff
    }
}
```

And you need to pass it when you call it:

```
ActionBlock<int> throttle = new ActionBlock<int>(
    action: i=>DoStuff(i, sources[i].Token),  //<--- modified
    dataflowBlockOptions: new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10,
        CancellationToken = cts.Token
    });
```

Then to cancel an individual task, call:

```
sources[i].Cancel();
```

Comment: I am clueless as to where this line goes, and why work is referenced.  work in my sample code is just an upper limit integer for the 'for loop' that is posting messages via throttle.post(i):    var sources = work.Select( w => new CancellationTokenSource()).ToList();

Comment: `work` has a `Length` property so I assumed it is an `IEnumerable` of some kind (e.g. an array or List). If so, you can use LINQ extension methods on it, such as `Select`. Selecting over the IEnumerable results in a list with the same number of elements, which is what you need-- one element per CancellationTokenSource.

Comment: I should probably remove the for loop as it is muddying the waters.  The actionBlock is inside a dataflow network " ITargetBlock<string> CreateProcessingNetwork()  "   A button click posts a string message to this ITargetBlock which I named 'HeadBlock' in the public class Form1. This post message is done with headBlock.Post(newjob2add_string);   My confusion lies in where to create the cancellation token and where to maintain this list of tokens...  inside ITargetBlock?

Comment: Depends where the code is that needs to be able to cancel the tasks. Put it somewhere within its scope.